# Laptop cpu staying 98 degree celcius for 1 minutes during rendering video

Tags: cpu, temperature

My Dell Inspiron 3501 having 11th gen 1135g7 with igpu iris xe is reaching around 98 degree (aprox for 1 minutes) continiously  during video rendering(of 4minutes). After one minute fan kicks on full speed and temperature goes down to around 85. For next 3 minutes temp was around 82-85 degree celcius. Is it safe for my motherboard and CPU?????????????
[temp graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSwbA.png)

Comment: No; Those temperatures are not normal; You have cores nearing their maximum temperatures; Did you disabled any cpu features designed to down clock your CPU?  Whatever codec your using to encode their video should be avoided

Comment: I dont disable any cpu feature. In Dell power manager I have changed my options from cool mode to Ultra performance mode, also i have changed my windows power slider to best performance. If i select "COOL" mode then temp only reaches upto 65 degree and my render time just doubles. But i am wonder how temperature can go as high as 98 and stays for 1 minute. I dont have installed any video codec externally. Whatever codec is there is only by windows update.

Comment: “Cool” mode is adjusting the clock of the CPU.  What does Dell indicate it’s supposed to do?  Your using something to encode the video which is using a codec

Comment: Yes Dell Cool mode actually decrease performance by limiting clock and increase fan spinning rate. I have two drivers installed HEVC video extension from device manufacturer and MPEG-2 Video extension. I dont know if these are working as codec. Also during rendering in Premier pro my integrated graphics (dont have discrete) are not utilized (only 2-5% utilization) and my cpu and ram utilization is 100%.

Comment: Both of those are a codec but there likely are not the codec Adobe Premier is using.  Adobe hardware acceleration requires specific hardware, it sounds like your iGPU, is NOT supported.

Comment: I have checked. Only for MPEG videos format it wont use iGPU but for every other format like AVI it is using iGPU(100%), CPU 70% and ram 85% But still my temp are around 88-92 during rendering for the . I think i have to use it in COOL mode where temp. decreases to 65 and time just doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is within limits and the fact that the Fan kicks in as it should and then the CPU cools down means the Fan is working properly.

So long as it works like this and cools down after a minute means your computer is working properly.

Consider your long term needs as eventually you may need a stronger computer, one geared to high loads. In particular a CPU designed to handle your load over long periods of time on a very good heat sink (the biggest that the manufacturer can fit in).

Answer (score 0):

These temperatures are acceptable, but high.

I don't know much about your hardware and video, but the video codec that you use
might not be able to use the GPU. Installing a good codecs pack might help with
a better codec that will offload the video work from the CPU to the GPU.

On Windows I recommend the
[K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Comment: You r right. Task manager tells GPU is not getting used and only CPU and ram is 100% utilized. I dont know much about codec for rendering. I am using adobe premier pro 2021. My laptop is new and every drivers are preinstalled. Will video codec will transfer video render work to GPU????? I have only integrated graphics Iris xe 80 eu. But in my opinion temp are too much and not acceptable. 100 is Tj for my processor so temps cant go above that and staying in 98 for a minute can damage it in long term. I know my processor can definitely bear that temp but i am sure my motherboard can't.

Comment: Adobe published an article indicating which GPU are supported for hardware encoding. Your question failed to identify the software and failed to identify what GPU you have. If the only GPU you have is the igpu that changes everything

Comment: I only have integrated graphics Iris Xe. Is it the reason Premier Pro isn't able to use my igpu??

Comment: This Adobe Premiere Pro [article](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/kb/gpu-and-gpu-driver-requirements-for-premiere-pro.html) might mean that it likes best Nvidia GPUs. Try to install a codec pack, and if this doesn't help then you will have to live with it. Ensure clean airways and perhaps invest in a cooling pad.